# Free space navigation Transporters attempting to pass through access restricted nodes

Tags: anylogic

I am attempting to model warehousing operations, using Free Space Transporters. To imitate a set picking route, I am using a combination of Walls and Rectangular Nodes with Access Restrictions. These Rectangular Nodes should act as 1-way gates.

Like so:

[image]

Here is that same image, with arrows indicating the intended path the Transporters should take to reach a given destination:

[image]

Actual Result - my transporters attempt to pass through a "1 way gate" from the wrong direction:

[image]

The configuration of the Transporters:

[image]

The configuration of the Rectangular Nodes:

[image]

Following the image, from left to right, the conditions for the Rectangular Nodes are:

```
Left : agent.getY() < self.getCenter().getY();
Middle :agent.getX() < self.getCenter().getX();
Right : agent.getY() > self.getCenter().getY();
```

What is going on here? Am I misunderstanding something about the use of Access Restriction? Why are my Transporters being routed through a restricted Node?

I've tried using agent.recalculateRoute() "On enter denied" as well as manually executing it over all my Transporters, but to no avail.

**EDIT**: I've reinvestigated at a lower run speed, and it seems to work - until it doesn't. After a while, some Transporters are just throwing themselves at a Node that should never be routed through, as depicted in the image above. **There are no error messages. No "no path found" error.** I have also tried lowering the amount of Transporters to a single entity, but it still attempts to route through blocked Nodes.

I've also tried changing around my "moveByTransporter" configurations, also to no avail. The transporters run into closed Nodes no matter how I set them up.

**EDIT2:** Trying again with `recalculateRoute()` in the "On enter denied" seems to improve things, with some Transporters going the right way after being rerouted. However, some Transporters are still getting stuck. Even repeated calls of `recalculateRoute()` just end up with them being routed through the restricted Node over and over again.

Here is an image. The console is showing the results of multiple calls of :

```
transporter.recalculateRoute();
traceln(transporter.getRouteData());
```

on the Transporter indicated by the tip of the arrow.

[image]

Comment: The logic looks good to me, I created a mockup model of this and it worked fine. The transporters only tried to go through a restricted node when I (wrongly) set the same condition for both directions, so they did not find a route and tried to go back on the shortest path. Are you sure your transporters can go around the racks in the middle and each condition is set correctly?

Comment: My conditions are correct. They're exactly as written above. Note that this isn't throwing an error or anything. I've reinvestigated at a lower run speed, and you're right, it seems to work - until it doesn't. After a while, some Transporters are just throwing themselves at a Node that should never be routed through, as depicted in the image above.